# Approach for Question Answer from thousand of text documents

Tags: nlp, question-answering

Recently I was working on natural language processing project, where task was to fetch the top-K paragraphs from thousands of text pages against user Queries.

I decided to go with following approach:

1. Vectorize each paragraph of thousands of text pages.
2. Store vectorized paragraphs in a Vector store.
3. Vectorize user query
4. Fetch top-k paragraphs based on cosine similarity against step-3 query vector.

is this approach ok, not ok, good, excellent?
Please let me know your views on this approach.